# How to bind the "\" key to crouch/duck?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I want to bind the "\" key to crouch/duck. I put `bind \ +duck` in the console, but if I press "\" my character doesn't duck.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: could help you : https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/3f826h/weird_bind_name_issue_anyone_got_a_solution/ctmjrfo

Answer (score 1):

You have to put it like this: bind / "+duck"

It has to be in the quotes so it recognizes the command

Comment: I think that is how you need to do it in a cfg file but that doesn't work :(

Comment: Have you tried "+crouch" instead of "+duck"?

Comment: Yeah did that already

Comment: Just a question, you put this in your console or your cfg?

Comment: You have to put this in your config as it will be loaded on each games

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it trough the options, and then if you want it also to be active on Ctrl then do Ctrl trough the console. That's how i get space AND mousescroll both to jump ...